# Forcing blue to go with red

Tags: color, logo, design-principles

I am using a reddish pink as a background `#ec4f48`. The client needs a blue that goes well with this background. I am currently using `#00b2de`. However, it is not blending in with the red like other colors like `#fecb00`. Does anyone have any suggestions for a color that would go well?

Comment: eh... Although I do lots of coding for food, I'm still not very adept at visualising hex colour codes :). In other words: do you have a pic of the two colours? Thanks!

Comment: @RandyJones thanks. abbott567 nailed it exactly with his answer. His idea of reducing the saturation fitted perfectly....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Red and Blue are both primary colours, which means they clash if their intensities are too similar.

If you must make them work together, then you need to zap some of that intensity out. The less saturated they are the less they will give you that fuzzy nausea feeling when you look at it.

Orange is naturally a complimentary colour to blue, so you could move your red in that direction. However if it must be #ec4f48 then you will have more luck taking the saturation out of the blue.

If you use something like #6fd2ea you will already see it starting to blend better.

[image: Blending Blue and Red]